# Какую выбрать регистрацию

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

У меня есть варианты регистрации на моём сайте, подскажите какой из этих вариантов будет удобен для пользователей больше всего:

1. Ajax+JS (Посылаю через ajax данные, а потом кидаю на эту же страницу)
2. PHP (Перенаправляю на эту же страницу где в шапке обработчик регистрации)
3. PHP (Сайт->Обработчик->Сайт)

Comment: *Ajax+JS* wtf?

Comment: 1 или 3 вариант

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку речь зашла об удобстве для пользователей возможно имеет смысл встроить регистрацию гугла, вк или на подобии того. Возможностей нынче предостаточно. Вот к примеру тот-же [гугловский оауз2](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2?hl=ru) Для себя я делал сам, но есть и готовые на подобии того что прикупил Яндекс - [логинза](http://loginza.ru/)

Answer (score 3):

Да пользователю то особо без-разницы. Главное чтобы работало без ошибок и тормозов)

Comment: Ну, а для кулц хакеров

Comment: А для хакеров по барабану. Если будет дырка - найдут.